# How can I interact with one web page while loading others on other windows/tabs using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

I am using Selenium in Python to write a program that needs to quickly interact with a number of different web pages, one after another after another.  Some of these pages take a long time to load, and if I simply write a script that visits a page, does what it needs to do on that page, then browses to the next one after finishing, it will be extremely slow; too slow, in fact, for my purposes.  As far as I can tell, Selenium always waits for a page to finish loading before it goes on to the next line in a script (which may be pressing a button, filling in a form field, etc.)  What I want to have the next page my script is going to browse to (or, better yet, the next several pages) loading while it is interacting with the current one.  Python doesn't need to do anything to a page while its loading, so it shouldn't slow anything down to make it work on a different page that is already fully loaded while the next page loads.  I just don't know how to make Selenium do it.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe create another instance of the web-driver and open the new URL in the new instance while maintaining the previous?

Comment: I tried that.  It doesn't seem to matter at all what the next line of a script is, even if it is opening a new instance of the webdriver.  The page has to finish loading before it will proceed.

Comment: Is there a dependency between these pages?  If not, then you could have separate threads that start up separate instances of webdriver and have multiple web-pages being tested.

Comment: No, there is no dependency at all.  What is done to one has nothing to do with what is done to any of the others.  However, it IS important that only one be active at a time.  I can't have multiple web pages actually being used at once, merely loaded.

Comment: To have multiple pages loaded then you'll need to have separate instances.

Comment: why can't you have multiple pages being used at once?  just curious.  If they do not depend on each other, it sounds like it doesn't really matter if they are all running at once.